# Declaring an array of objects

Tags: c++

i have to create an array of objects but i also have a parameterized constructor in my class which does some initialization to the attributes of class.
How to do this in c++?

Comment: A code example would go a long way.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Did you read it?

Answer (score 4):

With a "normal" initialization list?

Example:

```
struct S
{
    S(int, const std::string&) {}  // Just a dummy constructor
};

S array_of_s[2] = {
    S(123, "foo"),
    S(456, "bar")
};
```

Comment: Note that in C++11, you can almost always replace `S(...)` with `{...}` in the initialization, which saves on retyping the type how many times.